# Generic Cast xAttribute to bool

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is my code, which works perfectly except for one case: when I have an `xAttribute` of `bool`, so `xAttribute.Value == 1`. In this situation, `Convert` doesn't work for a numeric type.

Normally I would just use `output = (bool) xAttribute`, which works; but in this method I have a *generic* type, so I want to use that generic type along the lines of `output = (T) xAttribute`. How can I do this?

```
    public static bool TryGetValueFromAttribute<T>(
        this XElement element, 
        String attName, 
        out T output, 
        T defaultValue)
    {
        var xAttribute = element.Attribute(attName);
        if (xAttribute == null)
        {
            output = defaultValue;
            return false;
        }

        output = (T)Convert.ChangeType(xAttribute.Value, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should just add `where T : new(), class` in end of your function definition.

Comment: I thought I'd have a look at this when I had a spare moment and was amazed to find there doesn't seem to be a nice way of changing the string '1' to a bool. I would have thought the TypeConverter for bool would have done it but it'll only convert 'true' and 'false'. Quite an oversight if you ask me.

Comment: It doesn't work to say set `output` to `(T)xAttribute`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used the XmLConvert. Is an easy workaround. It even works with 0 and 1

Regards

```
        public static bool TryGetValueFromAttribute<T>(this XElement element, String attName, out T output, T defaultValue)
    {
        var xAttribute = element.Attribute(attName);
        if (xAttribute == null)
        {
            output = defaultValue;
            return false;
        }

        if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        {
            object value = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(xAttribute.Value);
            output = (T) value;

            return true;
        }

        output = (T)Convert.ChangeType(xAttribute.Value, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
```